# Cygwin work fine... Windows cmd giving error when doing 'git push'

Tags: git, ssh

I have a repo created in github, and when I push my commits from **cygwin** it works fine:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 407 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:-----------
```

However when I try to do exactly the same thing from **windows command line**, `git commit` works fine however `git push` gives me the following error:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.--------' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have a SSH added to github, but do I need to add another one for command line? Im new to this so would appreciate why this is happening.

Comment: Could you run `git push --verbose`. The additional info might help figuring out what is happening.

Comment: When I run this command in cmd, I get Permission denied (publickey) again

Comment: Windows cmd is attempting to use a different ssh key than the one configured in cygwin. Sorry I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure how to resolve, but that's what's causing your error.

Comment: On Windows, it is preferred to use the Git Bash especially provided for that. Can you try with this instead of the native Windows cmd ?

Also, did you check your ssh key is included in the ssh-agent of the cmd ?

Comment: Im afraid I cannot use gitbash on my pc as it kills it - how can i check for the ssh-agent ?

Comment: run `ssh -vvv 192.--------` from both and compare the output.

Comment: Could you also try `ssh -T git@github.com` (taken from [github-help](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/#platform-windows)).
But even they ask you to use **Git Bash**